# Whats the best way of presenting a sound design showreel ?

Tags: showreel, movies, demo, demo-reel

Most clients attention is short when asked to listen to sound alone. So I'm presuming its better to associate sound work with image. Without having to shoot a film just to showcase your sound and composition work, what is an effective way for showcasing the aesthetics and style of your work?

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem in answering this question is its vagueness. Is your client a film producer? An ad agency creative director? A theatre owner? A club owner looking for a DJ? A museum curator looking for the next interactive exhibit?

Your demo reel depends on how you answer the above. For film or TV, I'd recommend finding an exciting sequence from a movie or TV show and creating new sound design that is compelling, original and unique. Try to stay away from clichéd ideas and stock library sounds. The people judging your work want to be pleasantly surprised, and they don't necessarily want to watch the entire 2:30 demo to the end to get that response.

Designing to particle fountains or colors? Eh, that really depends on your target audience. For theatre or museums, maybe, but I believe most potential clients/employers want to experience something they can relate to.

Comment: Totally agree. I think it depends on the destination. You need to find material that fits your needs. Try to show that unique skills you have, and create sounds thinking on the kind of media you want to work on and who are going to see the reel.

Comment: I agree. Show client the part of your work that is related to the one he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1)Try to find an imaginary place, an ambience that you think your sound design fits to.

2)Try to relate your sounds to a color pattern. (eg. A happy sequence shown with pink color patterns)

3)Either ask for a help or pay a motion graphic artist to combine these elements or simply support your design with Stock photos or videos that you think suits best.

Comment: Relating to #3, most After Effects artists (myself included) will find it pretty easy to set up cool particle systems that can react to audio amplitude - frequency is harder. But it's a nice way to get some graphical "oomph" behind a sound-only reel.

Comment: Also relating to #3, consider offering pay-in-trade, if you don't have friends to do it.  If they hook you up on your reel, you can hook them up on a project.